# C Program to get Valid Input

Tags: c

I want to make a program that will convert kilo meters into meters. But in addition I want a condition where if user input any invalid data type rather than positive numerical value, program re-enforce user to input a valid value. Program only using loop & conditional constructs. Input should through scanf function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
main()
{
      int a, b;
          printf("Please Enter the Kilometers:");
          scanf("%d", &a);
         b=a*1000;
         printf("%d kilometers are %d meters", a, b);
          getch();
          }
```

Comment: write some code by yourself. people will help you here if you have some problem, but they wont write the code for you..

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I update a program in my question. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

The seems like a hw, so I will give an example of the desired behaviour for the input, but you will to include the logic of my example below in your actual code.

You could do it like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXINPUT 100

int main() {
  char input[MAXINPUT] = "";
  int length, i, ok;
  do {
    ok = 1;
    scanf("%s", input);
    length = strlen(input);
    if (input <= 0) {
      ok = 0;
      printf("Entered input is not a positive number\n");
    } else {
      for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (!isdigit(input[i])) {
          printf("Entered input is not a number\n");
          ok = 0;
        }
      }
    }
  } while (!ok);

  printf("Given input is a positive number\n");
  return 0;
}
```

This program will make the user input again if what (s)he typed is not a positive number or not a number (for example when he types a character). We use a flag named `ok` to check at the end of the loop if the input is OK or not.

Comment: G. Samaras! Thanks for giving an idea about the problem. But I am finding a simple and short method to resolve that problem. I am confined to use only sequential,conditional and loop constructs.

Comment: @AsifNaeem well.. he used only sequential,conditional and loop constructs.I don't see any problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int a, b;

    while(1){
        printf("Please Enter the Kilometers:");
        if(1==scanf("%d", &a) && a > 0)
            break;
        else
            scanf("%*[^\n]");
    }
    b=a*1000;
    printf("%d kilometers are %d meters", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code snippet to get and check whether the inputs are valid.

```js
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
 int input1,input2;
 int inputs_count; //to hold the (number of valid inputs)

 inputs_count=scanf("%i %i",&input1,&input2);

 if(inputs_count==1){
  //things to do when only 1 valid input
  puts("only 1 valid input");
 }else if(inputs_count==2){
  //things to do when both inputs are valid
  puts("both inputs are valid");
 }else{
  //things to do else (0 valid inputs...)
  puts("no valid inputs");
 }
 return 0;
}
```